# How to count rows in a dataframe where column values match column values in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following sample data

```
df1 = [[52, '1', '10'], [54, '1', '4'],
       [55, '2', '3'], [52, '1', '10'],
       [55, '2', '10'], [52, '1', '4']]
    
df = pd.DataFrame(df1, columns =['Cow', 'Lact', 'Procedure'])

df2 = [['52', '1'], ['53', '9'],
       ['54', '2'], ['55', '2']]
    
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2, columns =['Cow', 'Lact'])
```

The tables look like:

`df`:

```
    Cow Lact    Procedure
0   52  1        10
1   54  1        4
2   55  2        3
3   52  1        10
4   55  2        10
5   52  1        4
```

`df2`:

```
    Cow Lact
0   52  1
1   53  9
2   54  2
3   55  2
```

I would like to count the number of `procedure = 10` for each `Cow-Lact` combination in `df2` and then add a column to `df2` called `Tproc` that includes the count.

The output I am looking for is

```
    Cow Lact Tproc
0   52  1     2
1   53  9     0
2   54  2     0
3   55  2     1
```

The following filter does not work:

```
filt = [(df['Cow']==df2['Cow'])&(df['Lact']==df2['Lact'])&(df['Procedure']==10)]
```

My plan was then to use `.len` to get a count

```
df2['Tproc'] = df2.loc[filt].len
```

How can you filter a DataFrame based on values in another DataFrame to count the number of rows that satisfy the condition?

Comment: Your data types are not the same between columns of same name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `value_counts` and `reindex` your first dataframe before append the values to `Tproc` column:

```
df2['Tproc'] = (
    df1[df1['Procedure'] == '10'].value_counts(['Cow', 'Lact'])
       .reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df2[['Cow', 'Lact']]), fill_value=0).values
)
print(df2)

# Output
  Cow Lact  Tproc
0  52    1      2
1  53    9      0
2  54    2      0
3  55    2      1
```

Setup:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Cow': [52, 54, 55, 52, 55, 52],
                    'Lact': [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1],
                    'Procedure': ['10', '4', '3', '10', '10', '4']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Cow': [52, 53, 54, 55], 'Lact': [1, 9, 2, 2]})
```

Comment: Corralien  I like your code.  Thanks for the heads up re the datatypes.   In the real dataset the cow and lact variables are integers.   When I run the code you wrote with this example it works great.  When I run it with the integer variables and remove the df1.astype({'Cow'}:str) like below  df2['Tproc'] = (
    [df1['Procedure'] == '10'].value_counts(['Cow', 'Lact'])
       .reindex(df2[['Cow', 'Lact']], fill_value=0).values
)     I get the following, TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str also error if I leave in df['Cow']

Comment: @JohnH. I updated my answer according to your comment. Take care, it's not `.value_counts(['Cow', 'Lact'])` but `.value_counts([['Cow', 'Lact']])`.

Answer (score 1):

You could `merge` + `groupby` + `sum`:

```
tmp = df2.merge(df.astype(str), on=['Cow','Lact'], how='left')
out = tmp['Procedure'].eq('10').groupby([tmp['Cow'], tmp['Lact']]).sum().reset_index(name='Tproc')
```

Output:

```
  Cow Lact  Tproc
0  52    1      2
1  53    9      0
2  54    2      0
3  55    2      1
```

Answer (score 1):

use `groupby()` + `size()` and then `merge()`

```
out = df2.merge(
    df[df['Procedure'] == '10'].groupby(['Cow', 'Lact']).size().reset_index(name='Tproc').astype(str), 
    how='left', 
    on=['Cow','Lact']
).fillna(0)
```

output:

> ```
>   Cow Lact Tproc
> 0 52  1   2
> 1 53  9   0
> 2 54  2   0
> 3 55  2   1
> ```